# Proof $\dim \ker (T-\lambda) = \text{codim(ran} (T-\lambda)$ for $T$ compact

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Let $\lambda\neq 0 \in\mathbb{C}$.My professor mentioned in a lecture that $\dim \ker (T-\lambda) = \text{codim(ran} (T-\lambda)$ holds for $T$ compact operator on a Banach space. We only discussed the proof for when $T$ is self adjoint on a hilbert space. I believe this is called "Riesz-Schauder" theorem but I haven't had any luck finding it online. I already know that both sides of the equation are finite. Does anyone know a proof that could go here or a reference?

Comment: You should look up the Fredholm alternative.

Comment: @janes Generally speaking, that should be $\ker(T - \lambda) = \mathrm{(codim(ran}(T - \lambda)^*))$, unless we are meant to assume that $T$ is self-adjoint. Either way, please edit your question to clarify what you mean here

Comment: @BenGrossmann Are you sure? I am here looking for a reference so I am limited in what I know about the theorem, nevermind whether we are talking about the same result or not

Comment: @janes I've thought about it, I was wrong; sorry about that. However, your statement is missing something: this statement only holds for non-zero $\lambda$.

Comment: @janes Pedersen's *Analysis Now* proves this for (not necessarily self-adjoint) operators on a Hilbert space. Would that result be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @janes One point of interest: if you can prove that the statement holds for finite rank operators $T$, then it's easy to extend this result to the case where $T$ is compact using the singular value decomposition for compact operators.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, we need $\lambda\neq 0$, thanks. I'm most interested in the banach space case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is in rudin functional analysis in the middle of the compact operators section